# How add sorting on comments by dropdown in wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

I want to show the data by sorting in wordpress using a dropdown. So, how add sorting on comments by dropdown in wordpress ?

Comment: You will need to do custom php code for this.

Answer (score 0):

The function [get_comments();](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_comments) has an orderby argument that you can pass in order to change the order that they are shown:

```
$orderby
(string) (optional) Set the field used to sort comments.
Default: comment_date_gmt

$order
(string) (optional) How to sort $orderby. Valid values:
'ASC' - Ascending (lowest to highest).
'DESC' - Descending (highest to lowest).
Default: DESC
```

You should then be able to edit the HTML of the template file inside comments.php or single.php and do a POST to self with the value, changing the query.